# Nuxt3 - [Vue warn]: Component inside <Transition> renders non-element root node that cannot be animated

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I'm getting these two vue warnings:

[image: nuxt3 vue warnings]

I validated that all components, pages and layouts have a single root element.

Layouts:

**default.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>
```

**main.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div class="relative">
    <NavBarTop class="sticky top-0 z-40" />
    <!-- Content -->
    <div class="container mx-auto lg:mt-5">
      <div class="grid grid-cols-12 lg:px-8 p-3.5 mx-auto lg:gap-x-9">
        <!-- left column -->
        <div class="col-span-12 lg:block lg:col-span-3 place-items-start">
          <NavMain class="hidden lg:flex" />
          <slot name="left-column"></slot>
        </div>
        <!-- Center -->
        <div class="col-span-12 lg:col-span-6">
          <slot name="content"></slot>
        </div>
        <!-- right- -->
        <div class="order-first col-span-12 lg:col-span-3 lg:order-none">
          <slot name="right-column"></slot>
        </div>
      </div>
      <slot />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

**app.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div class="font-inter">
    <ToastNotification />
    <NuxtLayout>
      <NuxtPage />
    </NuxtLayout>
  </div>
</template>
```

The app "works" as expected up until `<NuxtLayout>`. `<ToastNotification>` is in the DOM but nothing else in the body tag.

**package.json**

```json
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
     ...
    "nuxt": "3.0.0-rc.9",
     ...
  },
  "dependencies": {
   ...

    "nuxt3": "^3.0.1-rc.0-27821553.ab125bd",
   ...

  }
}
```

Comment: Try with the latest `3.0 stable` rather than the RC.

Comment: Also, why do you have 2 nuxt? Keep only one.

Comment: 3.0 version did the trick!

Comment: I've posted my answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP fixed the issue by using the latest stable `3.0` version of Nuxt.